# How to break out of recursion when checking for empty directories (Java)

Tags: java, file, recursion, metadata

[image: Screenshot showing Desktop Directory shown as empty when it's obviously not]

I have a Directory Lister program that simply lists directories/subdirectories/files in a JTable, and it does this recursively (one of the requirements). There were several conditions that had to be met (i.e. checking for empty directories, checking if a folder/file exists, etc), and everything seems to be working great after testing. 
The problem is that it does find empty directories, but if I choose to open a directory that contains empty subdirectories, my Dialog box will open each time the recursion finds it. What I've discovered is that it's showing the metadata (the "." and ".." files which equal 4kb on my Linux machine) as empty. This is fine if the folder ONLY contains those. For example, my Documents folder has "4kb" of data, but the program says it's empty.

These are the two methods for the entire process:

```
    //this method creates the File object, and calls 
    //the method containing the recursive function

    public void showDirectoryContents(String basePath) { 

    try {
        File file = new File(basePath); //creation of File Object
        enumerateDirectory(file); //enumerateDirectory method call
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
    //The method for all the required File conditions and recursive function

    public void enumerateDirectory(File f) {

    File[] theFiles = f.listFiles();

    String fileType = ""; //This will display as either a "Folder" or a "File" in the JTable

    if(f.isFile())
    {
        fileType = "File";
        gui.updateListing(f.getAbsolutePath(), getSizeString(f.length()), fileType, new Date(f.lastModified()).toString());
    }
    else if(f.isDirectory())
    {
        fileType = "Folder";
        gui.updateListing(f.getAbsolutePath(), getSizeString(f.length()), fileType, new Date(f.lastModified()).toString());
    }
    if(f.isDirectory() && f.list().length == 0) {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(gui, "That folder is empty.", "OOPS!", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        gui.setAddressLabelText(""); //clear the Address Label so it doesn't show the directory.
        while(gui.tableModel.getRowCount() > 0) {
            for(int i = 0; i < gui.tableModel.getRowCount(); i++) {
                gui.tableModel.removeRow(i); //remove the empty directory from the JTable before the dialog window pops up.
            }
        }
    }

    /*
    This code will remove a non-existent folder/file form the Address Label, and remove it from the JTable.
    Originally, it was listing it on the label and putting a 0 KB file on the Table

    The parameter "gui" in the JOptionPane was created due to the ERROR_MESSAGE popping up on a 2nd monitor if the user has one (the code was tested on dual monitors). This way, it shows up directly in front of the gui.
     */
    if(!f.exists()) {
        try {
            gui.setAddressLabelText("");
            int action = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(gui, "That file does not exist.", "ERROR", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            if(action == 0) {
                while (gui.tableModel.getRowCount() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < gui.tableModel.getRowCount(); i++) {
                        gui.tableModel.removeRow(i);
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch(NullPointerException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }
    if(f.isDirectory())
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < theFiles.length; i++) {
            enumerateDirectory(theFiles[i]); //recursive function to get all files in specified folder
        }
    }
}
```

How can I prevent the dialog box from showing up if the directory contains subdirectories? Is there a method that states (in plain English) "if the folder contains subfolders, keep iterating"??

I am not familiar with the Path class yet, and I don't yet know how to use FileFilter for this. Any tips/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you want to display a dialog box for every empty directory you encounter, you're doing it. If you don't want to do that, what *do* you want to do?

Comment: Let's say I have a directory that has nothing in it. For example, my Documents folder is empty, and the program tells me it's empty. However, the Desktop is not empty since it contains subdirectories. The program is showing the box for directories with subdirectories that have the 4kb of metadata. I only want the dialog to show up if it's a directory with nothing in it, not loop through every subdirectory and tell me it's empty.

Comment: If a directory contains subdirectories, it isn't empty, and Java won't say it is. How are you constructing the `File[]` array? Are you using a filter? You need to show that code. Or else I still don't understand your question.

Comment: File [] theFiles = f.listFiles();  (f is my File object parameter in the method).

Comment: The recursion stops once it reaches any 4kb folder (metadata). I click "OK" on the dialog telling me it's empty, then it goes through the recursion again, listing the other folders/files. I don't want it to do this. I only want it to tell me it's empty if it has no subdirectories. I hope I'm explaining this correctly.

Comment: `File.listFiles()` returns a list of files *or directories* contained in the specified directory, or `null` if the specified file isn't a directory. I do not understand how or indeed whether you are seeing the behaviour you're describing, and you haven't posted enough code for anybody to try to replicate it.

Comment: I will edit my post and show the entire method. It's not terribly long.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I have a directory containing an empty directory and nothing else, and only the empty directory is shown as empty.

Comment: @EJP I added a screenshot to my post to show what is happening. For the Desktop folder, the JDialog appears twice, but still shows all the subdirectories/files as it should. There is something wrong with my recursion in my opinion. I just don't know how to fix it....yet.